You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this RegisterScreen Widget
This happens because you used a BuildContext that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

You added a new provider in your main.dart and performed a hot-reload.
To fix, perform a hot-restart.

The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
other routes will not be able to access that provider.

You used a BuildContext that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.
Make sure that RegisterScreen is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.


class RegisterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<RegisterScreen> createState() => _RegisterScreenState();
}

class _RegisterScreenState extends State<RegisterScreen> {

  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _fullNameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _confirmPasswordController = TextEditingController();
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _emailController.dispose();
    _fullNameController.dispose();
    _passController.dispose();
    _confirmPasswordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => SportsBloc(AuthService(), LoginAuth()),
      child: BlocListener<SportsBloc,SportsState>(
        listener: (context,state){

          if(state is GetRegisterState){
            UserCredential userCredential = state.userCredential;
            if(userCredential.user != null){
              context.read<SportsBloc>().add(GetUploadInfoEvent(state.email, state.fullName, state.userUid));
            } else {
              setState(() {
                isLoading = false;
              });
              Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Failed to register..");
            }
          }
          if(state is GetUploadInfoState){
            bool isSuccessful = state.isSuccessful;
            if(isSuccessful){
              setState(() {
                isLoading = false;
              });
              Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Account Successfully created");
              Get.offAndToNamed(AppRouting.homeScreen);
            } else {
              // unregister the user
              setState(() {
                isLoading = false;
              });
              Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Failed to create an account");
              context.read<SportsBloc>().add(GetDeleteUserEvent());
            }
          }

          if(state is GetDeleteUserState){
            bool isDeleted = state.isDeleted;
            if(isDeleted){
              print("Account successfully deleted");
            } else {
              print("Failed to delete account");
            }
          }

        },
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            body: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Center(child: Image.asset("assets/images/sport.png",width: 200,height: 150,fit: BoxFit.cover,)),
                    Text("Register",style: Utils.getBoldFont().copyWith(fontSize: 30),),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                    Text("Email",style: Utils.getMediumFont(),),
                    const SizedBox(height: 5,),
                    CustomEditText(hint: "Email", iconData: Icons.email_outlined,
                      textEditingController: _emailController, isPass: false,),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                    Text("Email",style: Utils.getMediumFont(),),
                    const SizedBox(height: 5,),
                    CustomEditText(hint: "Full Name", iconData: Icons.person,
                      textEditingController: _fullNameController, isPass: false,),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                    Text("Password",style: Utils.getMediumFont(),),
                    const SizedBox(height: 5,),
                    CustomEditText(hint: "Password", iconData: Icons.password,
                      textEditingController: _passController, isPass: true,),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                    Text("Confirm Password",style: Utils.getMediumFont(),),
                    const SizedBox(height: 5,),
                    CustomEditText(hint: "Confirm Password", iconData: Icons.password,
                      textEditingController: _confirmPasswordController, isPass: true,),
                    const SizedBox(height: 40,),
                    Center(child: Text("Have an account? Login",style: Utils.getMediumFont().copyWith(fontSize: 17),)),
                    const SizedBox(height: 30,),
                    Center(
                      child: CustomButton(
                        text: "Register",
                        onTap: () {
                          // REGISTER USER
                          var email = _emailController.text.trim();
                          var fullName = _fullNameController.text.trim();
                          var password = _passController.text.trim();
                          var confirmPassword = _confirmPasswordController.text.trim();

                          // Perform validation checks
                          if (!_showToast(email, "Email cannot be empty")) return;
                          if (!_showToast(fullName, "Full Name cannot be empty")) return;
                          if (!_showToast(password, "Password cannot be empty")) return;
                          if (!_showToast(confirmPassword, "Confirm Password cannot be empty")) return;

                          if (!_isValidEmail(email)) return;
                          if (!_checkPasswordLength(password, "Password length cannot be less than 6")) return;
                          if (!_checkPasswordLength(confirmPassword, "Confirm Password length cannot be less than 6")) return;
                          if (!_doPasswordsMatch(password, confirmPassword)) return;

                          // All validations passed, proceed with registration
                          setState(() {
                            isLoading = true;
                          });

                          context.read<SportsBloc>().add(GetRegisterEvent(
                              email,
                              password,
                              fullName,
                              FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid
                          ));
                        },
                        isLoading: isLoading,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  bool _showToast(String value, String msg) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: msg);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  bool _checkPasswordLength(String password, String msg) {
    if (password.length < 6) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: msg);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  bool _isValidEmail(String email) {
    String emailPattern = r'^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$';
    RegExp regExp = RegExp(emailPattern);
    if (!regExp.hasMatch(email)) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Email is not valid");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  bool _doPasswordsMatch(String password, String confirmPassword) {
    if (password != confirmPassword) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Both Passwords do not match");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

}




Where does the error is happening ?  I will asume that just trying to push the page;  so you're invoking a BlocProvider that is not part of the parent Provider / MultiProvider, if that's the case you'll need to add SportsBloc to the provider parent of this screen.

But I'm already providing bloc through the bloc provider on top of the widget tree

You could extract your Scaffold into a new widget, or wrap it with a Builder.
context.read<SportsBloc>().add(GetRegisterEvent()) in onTap is using the BuildContext of RegisterScreen which is above BlocProvider
